# get author from Confluence CQL Search String Version 3

Tags: get, cql, confluence, author

How is it possible to get the author (from pages, comments, etc) for the search results with the Confluence CQL API Version 3.0?

For my search the API search Version 3.0 is necessary

This one gaves no Content snippet back:
https://myconfluence.site/rest/searchv3/1.0/search?queryString=SEARCHTEXT&startIndex=0&where=conf_all

The function "&expand=body.storage" doesn't work for me.

The only results i get are:
id, 
title, 
bodyTextHighlights, 
url, 
searchResultContainer 
--name
--url
friendlyDate, 
contentType, 
metadata,

Anybody an idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another search API to get the page creator and this works for me.

Instead of **body.storage**, you can expand **history** to get the creator of a page.

The rest call

```
/rest/api/content/search?cql=id=<pageId>&expand=history
```

leads to an output like this and you can walk through till the creator

```
{
"results": [{
    "id": "123456",
    ...
    "history": {
        "latest": true,
        "createdBy": {
            ...
            "username": "Some.Name",
            "displayName": "Some Name",
            "userKey": "123456"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Iam dont need /rest/api, i need the search query from /rest/search3/v1.0/... But with this i cant get the history or other parameters in expand. Any idea?

Comment: I don't see why you can't use /rest/api, as there shouldn't be any restrictions. Or do I miss your use case? If so, please provide more details.

Comment: i need this string (searchv3) for the correct order of the search results. Its necessary for me. But i also need the author informations...

Comment: which order do you need? you can also order by quite any field (e.g. id) using: /rest/api/content/search?cql=id=<pageId>+order+by+id+asc&expand=history

Comment: I know, but this is why i have to use the v3 API. /rest/api is not possible for my usecase. I have to take /searchv3/. But i need the author and created date.

Comment: I still don't see a reason why you must use searchv3, but I did some further research and you simply can't control the output of the search results. There is no "expand" parameter. As searchv3 is private there is no documentation, but the REST API browser does not show any expand.